# Solr merge two shards in one

Tags: solr, sharding

I've been using and watching Solr documentation for replication and shard handling in a Solr Cloud cluster.

I can create and remove replicas without problems.
I can split a shard easily (It create two new shards and disable the old one).

```
shard1 -> shard1_0 and shard1_1
```

But can I do the opposite operation ?

```
shard1_0 and shard1_1 -> shard 1
```

I have not seen anything in the documentation that answers my need.

Comment: are you talking about SolrCloud or master-slave replication?

Comment: Dorry, I was talking about Solr Cloud. I'm editing my question.

Comment: As far as I know, no, there is no opposite operation (except for manually merging the cores and updating the metadata json). There usually isn't a reason for merging shards, but I'm sure a patch would be welcome if there is actual need.